# controlling drc simulator from external program

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am wondering where I might find example code on controlling and reading sensor data in the drc simulator from an external program controller? Every piece of documentation I found merely discusses controlling the gazebo from within a plugin that gazebo will itself load. I found a black page on ros that is title about controlling gazebo from ros, but as I said, the page is blank and therefore useless. So, where might find examples of using this with an external program controller and NOT a plugin? And how about examples on reading the sensor data from something other an XML type file that the simulator loads?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/534/controlling-drc-simulator-from-external-program/) by [aqiruse](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/110/aqiruse/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 48 on 2012-12-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2012-12-23**:
Can you include links to the content that you found inadequate?

**Comment by [aqiruse](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/110/aqiruse/) on 2012-12-27**:
The link on controlling gazebo from ROS entitled "Creating a Gazebo plugin that talks to ROS" is blank. The link I went to that I found inadequate was the following:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/Write%20a%20Gazebo%20Plugin%20that%20Talks%20to%20ROS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Use the tutorials from the [gazebo tutorial page](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials).

As part of DRC you're using the "standalone" gazebo 1.3 and not the gazebo that's within ROS.
For controlling the robot from an external node you probably want the [drc specific tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/drcsim/).

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) with karma: 508 on 2012-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0